# Fixing Table Alignment in Yahoo Mail when sending HTML Emails

Tags: email, html-email

I am trying to center align my html emails.

**yahoo email** has a bug and does not align to the center. it simply does a left margin alignment.

this is a well known bug. I have tried following the advice of [litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/fixing-table-alignment-in-yahoo-mail) and placing an outer table over my content table and then using a `style="table-layout:fixed;"`

But this solution no longer seems to work.

I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas how to get around this.

Below is my code:

```
<table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="12" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
       <td>
          <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="6002">
             <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#70bbd9">
                    Row 1
                </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0PX;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="table-layout:fixed; margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
    <td width="100%" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <table width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f0efe8">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="640">

                        <!--Code here-->

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

The style on the body is useful to include, I can't remember if it is to combat the Yahoo! left-align, but it fixes something. Adding `margin:0 auto;` in additon to the fixed table layout on your 100% wrapping table should do the trick. It is always useful to have a starting template for your emails, with a 100% wrapping table with the mentioned styles and a fixed-width table inside to house the main content of your email. It's also worth mentioning that "height" isn't supported for tables, and height 100% on a `<td>` could cause you problems as it doesn't work in quite the same way as 100% width.

Comment: "Cellspacing" and "cellpadding" also have limited support (in Outlook I believe) so it is best to avoid these and always set it to "0" on a <table>, in terms of borders it will be more consistent in terms of rendering to use the "CSS border" style, as they are widely supported when used on a `<td>` or `<table>`, while the HTML attribute "border" is limited and only works consistently on a `<table>`.